# I want to return function after doing mapSeries

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I want to return querys(function) after doing mapSeries

how do i this? please help me!

```
async querys(querys) {
        const pool = await poolPromise;
        if (pool != null) {
            const transaction = new sql.Transaction(pool);
            
            await new Promise(resolve => transaction.begin(resolve));
            const request = new sql.Request(transaction)
    
            try {
                let results = []
                // ------------- Series -------------
                async.mapSeries(querys, async (query, callback) => {
                                console.log('----------')
                                const result = await request.query(query);
                                // return result.recordset;
                                results.push(result.recordset);
                }, async (err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        throw new Error(err);
                    }
                    else {
                        await transaction.commit();
                    }
                });
                console.log('hello');
                // -------------- return ---------------
                return [true, results];
            } catch(err) {
                await transaction.rollback();
                return [false, err];
            }
        }
        else {
            return [false, 'connect error'];
        }
    },
```

querys

expected output : [true, [object], [object] ... ]

real output : [true, []]

Comment: What is `async` and what is `sql`? Which libraries are you using?

Answer (score -1):

self answer

added promise

```
async querys(querys) {
        return new Promise( async resolve => {
            const pool = await poolPromise;

            if (pool != null) {
                const transaction = new sql.Transaction(pool);
                
                await new Promise(resolve => transaction.begin(resolve));
                const request = new sql.Request(transaction)
        
                async.mapSeries(querys, async (query, callback) => {
                    const result = await request.query(query);

                    return result.recordset;
                }
                , async (err, results) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);

                        console.log('rollback');
                        await transaction.rollback();

                        resolve({isError: true, err: '데이터 가져오기 오류'});
                    }
                    else {
                        await transaction.commit();

                        resolve({isError: false, data: results})
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                resolve({isError: true, err: '데이터에 연결할 수 없습니다.'});
            }
        });
    },
```